# Generating a data validation list and sorting it alphabetically

Tags: vba, excel

The following code clears 11 columns that contain lists that are used for data validation on another worksheet. This list is constantly changing due to records being added/removed from the source data. Basically I'm checking every value in a column, and if it meets all of my criteria I'm adding it to my data validation column (after making sure it doesn't already exist there).

Once I've populated my 11 columns, I sort each one alphabetically. **This is the portion of my code that I don't like**. While it doesn't explicitly `select` anything, I can see on my worksheet the last column that was sorted because it is selected.

What I'm wondering is if there's a better way to dynamically generate this list alphabetically without having to use `.Sort` - possibly populating an array and then sorting it alphabetically? I've never sorted an array in VBA, so I'm not sure **1. If it's even more efficient** and **2. What is the best method to sort an array, if that's the approach I should take here?**

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub PopulateAllDataValidationLists()

    Dim sht As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, listcol As Long

    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Data Validation")

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        sht2.Range("A2:K500").ClearContents

        For i = 1 To 11
            listcol = sht.Rows("1:1").Find(What:=sht2.Cells(1, i).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

            For j = 2 To sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, listcol).End(xlUp).Row
                If IsError(Application.Match(sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value, sht2.Range(ColumnLetter(i) & ":" & ColumnLetter(i)), 0)) And _
                sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value <> "" And _
                sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value <> "UNK" And _
                sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value <> "xxx" And _
                sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value <> "yyy" And _
                sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value <> "zzz" And _
                sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value <> "yxz" And _
                sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value <> "zyx" And _
                Len(sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value) <= 3 Then
                    sht2.Cells(sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1, i).Value = sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value
                End If
            Next j

        Next i

        'Sort all alphabetically
        For i = 1 To 11
            Worksheets("Data Validation").Sort.SortFields.Clear
            Worksheets("Data Validation").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(ColumnLetter(i) & "2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

            With Worksheets("Data Validation").Sort
                .SetRange Range(ColumnLetter(i) & "2:" & ColumnLetter(i) & sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row)
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        Next i

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function ColumnLetter(colnum As Long) As String

    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, colnum).Address, "$")(1)

End Function
```

An example of data in a column:

[image: img1]

Comment: Can you provide any sample data from the sheets?

Comment: Funnily enough, I've been working on a data structure that achieves precisely this. Annoyingly it's still a work in progress, but the basic concept is that I encapsulate an `ArrayList` and raise events whenever the order or content change. You might be able to make use of the [working branch](https://github.com/Greedquest/VBA-Toolbox/tree/synchro-list-v3?files=1) though. Message me on chat if you'd like some more details, the whole thing will hopefully go up on CR fairly soon

Comment: @PeterT I added a small example of what data in a column would look like.

Comment: @Greedo Interesting - I'll take a look at this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor your code and add  `Worksheets("Data Validation").Range("A1").Select` to the end to clear the selection.

### Refactored Code

Changes:

- `ColumnLetter()`: Removed
- sht2: Replaced using a `With` block.
- `For j`: Changed to `For item`.  `item.Value` is much easier to distinguish than `sht.Cells(j, listcol).Value`
- `.Range("A1").Select`:  Added to clear the dreaded selected column
- Cell reference fully qualified for the Sort ranges (I am surprised that the code would run without `Worksheets("Data Validation")` being the ActiveSheet.
- `sht2.Range("A2:K500").ClearContents`: Replaced made dynamic using `sht2.Range("A1:K1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents`

---

```
Sub PopulateAllDataValidationLists()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, listcol As Long
    With Worksheets("Data Validation")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        .Range("A1:K1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents
        Dim columnName As String
        Dim InvalidValues As Variant

        InvalidValues = Array("UNK", "xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "yxz", "zyx")

        Dim rColumn As Range, item As Range
        For i = 1 To 11
            columnName = .Cells(1, i).Value
            With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
                listcol = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:=columnName, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
                Set rColumn = Range(.Cells(1, listcol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, listcol).End(xlUp))
            End With

            For Each item In rColumn
                If item.Value <> "" Then
                    If IsError(Application.Match(item.Value, .Columns(i), 0)) And _
                       IsError(Application.Match(item.Value, InvalidValues, 0)) And _
                       Len(item.Value) <= 3 Then
                        .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1, i).Value = item
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Cells(2, i), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            Dim target As Range
            Set target = Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp))

            With .Sort
                .SetRange target
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        Next i
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

### Other Method

There are many ways that you can sort the data:

- System.Collection.ArrayList : [ArrayList Class (System.Collections) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.2), [VBA for smarties: ArrayList](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arraylist_en.html)
- System.Collections.SortedList: [SortedList Class (System.Collections) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.7.2), [VBA voor smarties: SortedList](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Sortedlist_en.html), [VBScript Scripting Techniques: SortedLists - Rob van der Woude](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_data_sortedlist.php)
- Bubble Sort: [VBA Arrays - Bubble Sort - BetterSolutions.com](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/sorting-bubble-sort.htm)
- Quick Sort: [VBA Arrays - Quick Sort - BetterSolutions.com](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/sorting-quick-sort.htm)

Here is an example of how you can use an `ADODB.Recordset` to create a table in memory to sort and potentially filter the data.

### RSSort: Class

```
Option Explicit
Public FieldName As String
Private Const adVarChar = 200
Private Const adOpenKeyset = 1
Private Const adUseClient = 3
Private Const adLockPessimistic = 2
Private rs As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    FieldName = "Values"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With rs
        .Fields.Append FieldName, adVarChar, 255
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockPessimistic
        .Open
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub AddNew(ByVal item As Variant)
    rs.AddNew FieldName, item
End Sub

Public Property Get Filter() As String
    Filter = rs.Filter
End Property

Public Property Let Filter(ByVal sFilter As String)
    rs.Filter = sFilter
End Property

Public Sub Sort(Optional SortAscending As Boolean = True)
    rs.Sort = FieldName & IIf(SortAscending, " ASC", " DESC")
End Sub

Public Function ToArray() As Variant
    Dim data As Variant, results As Variant
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        ReDim results(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        ToArray = results
        Exit Function
    End If
    rs.MoveFirst
    data = rs.GetRows(rs.RecordCount)
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(data, 2) + 1, 1 To 1)

    Dim r As Long

    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        results(r + 1, 1) = data(0, r)
    Next

    ToArray = results
End Function
```

### Demo Code

```
Sub RSSorterPopulateAllDataValidationLists()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim data As Variant
    Dim c As Long

    With Worksheets("Data Validation")
        .Range("A1:K1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents
        For c = 1 To 11
            data = getValidationValues(.Columns(c), "", "UNK", "xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "yxz", "zyx")
            .Cells(2, c).Resize(UBound(data)).Value = data
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function getValidationValues(MatchColumn As Range, ParamArray InvalidValues() As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim sorter As New RSSorter
    Dim col As Range
    Dim ColumnHeader As String
    ColumnHeader = MatchColumn.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Dim vExcluded As Variant
    vExcluded = InvalidValues

    With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
        Dim item As Range
        Set col = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:=ColumnHeader, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not col Is Nothing Then
            For Each item In Range(col.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, col.Column).End(xlUp))
                If item.Value <> "" Then
                    If IsError(Application.Match(item.Value, MatchColumn, 0)) And _
                       IsError(Application.Match(item.Value, vExcluded, 0)) And _
                       Len(item.Value) <= 3 Then
                        sorter.AddNew item
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With
    sorter.Sort
    getValidationValues = sorter.ToArray
End Function
```

### Edit

- `sht`replaced with `With Worksheets("Sheet 1")`
- Constants (adOpenKeyset, adUseClient, adLockPessimistic) added to completely convert from early binding to late binding.
- The ADODB library `"Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library"` removed from original workbook

Comment: This is great! Is there a library that I need to use for RSSorter? Getting  user-defined type not defined.

Comment: Although I will say that the refactored code works nicely (except it was missing a `Set` line for `sht` which I easily added). Additionally, I had to get rid of `Range("A1").Select` since that sheet is hidden and not active when sorting - but it looks to run faster!

Comment: @dwirony  Thanks for accepting my answer. I resolved the issues(see edits).  Late night

Comment: Haha no worries - I was tired when this original script, I should've created an array and checked against it instead of all those `And`s... sloppy by me.